# Сравнение двух таблиц без учета регистра

Tags: oracle, sql

Надо сравнить две таблицы содержащие фамилии без учета регистра. Например, в первой таблице содержится фамилия Иванов, а во второй есть фамилия ИВАНОВ и Иванов, надо чтобы поиск в результате выдал два Иванова, а не один.

Comment: @SergeyNeo46, уточните вопрос. Вы хотите найти записи в двух таблицах без учёта регистра? Или вы хотите найти записи, которые есть в обеих таблицах без учёта регистра? Или ещё что-нибудь?

Comment: При сравнении используйте приведение к одному регистру.

Comment: я сравнивал две таблице в условии писал T1.Familiya = T2.Familiya, но он находит не все фамилии из за регистра! Вот и хочу сравнить без учета регистра.

Comment: А что, в оракле уже отменили функции UPPER/LOWER?

Comment: А по подробнее.

Comment: @SergeyNeo46, LOWER(T1.Surname) = LOWER(T2.Surname)

Comment: sorry, мне просто подумалось, что человек, допущенный до оракла, уже хотя бы пролистал учебник для чайников.

Comment: Sorry, не читал!
Спасибо за ответы, вроде все получилось!

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте, я не большой специалист в PL SQL но как вам уже написали здесь стоит использовать функции upper\lower [О них можно почитать например тут](http://www.sqlinfo.net/oracle/oracle_function_upper_lower.php)

Ваш пример выглядел бы как-то так

```
LOWER(T1.Familiya) = LOWER(T2.Familiya)
```